# Unable to get Default value in MudSelect

Tags: mudblazor

```
 <MudSelect T="ModelName" Label="Select Name" @bind-Value="?????????">
           @foreach (var item in LoadNames)
            {
             <MudSelectItem Value="@(new ModelName{ scid = item.scid, name= item.name })">@item.name</MudSelectItem>
            }
 </MudSelect>
```

Unable to bind with the default Value,
Here is the Default value

```
public ModelName defaultValue { get; set; } = new ModelName { scid = 101, name = "xyz" };
```

how to Bind the Default value with the Model

Answer (score 1):

You were close, set the `@bind-Value` to `defaultValue`, here is a [working example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GawnEpHvVsbcDnXL):

```
<MudSelect T="ModelName" Label="Select Name" @bind-Value="@defaultValue">
    @foreach (var item in LoadNames)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@item">@item.name</MudSelectItem>
    }
 </MudSelect>

@code {
    public ModelName defaultValue { get; set; } = new ModelName { scid = 101, name = "xyz" };

    private List<ModelName> LoadNames = new List<ModelName>();  

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        LoadNames.Add(new ModelName {name="test 1", scid = 1});
        LoadNames.Add(new ModelName {name="test 2", scid = 2});
        LoadNames.Add(defaultValue);
    }

    public class ModelName {
        public int scid {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the default value from the existing items instead of Adding new ones? Secondly i am using ValueChanged="value => SelectedUser(value)" Value="@defaultValue"

Comment: Where are the existing items? You didnt show that in your code.